# Stack Exchange API Licensing Compliance

Tags: support, api, attribution

We are implementing an app that searches Stack Overflow content. When search results are rendered, we will make sure all the sources and authors are attributed with proper links (clickable) to the source.

But when users have not yet clicked in the search, no reference of Stack Overflow is present.

Is this behavior complying to the Stack Exchange Terms of Services? The https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#attribution is a bit vague when mentioning about data being searched by a search engine.

Comment: Do you mean using the official API to search the content, or web crawling?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Our attribution guidelines are the same.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer nor do I play one on TV, so I can't promise anything here, but...

That seems reasonable. If you're not displaying any of the content from Stack Overflow, there's nothing to attribute. The second you do, you should provide the items described in the TOS section you linked to.

I'd also label the search clearly, but that's just good UI. :)

If anything's amiss, you'll hear from us with a friendly warning and have a chance to fix things up.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  That helps.