# Usage and attribution of SE tags in third party apps

Tags: support, tags, api, attribution

Are API users allowed to persist the tags queried over the SE API (/tags) and if so, how should the attribution look like and where should it be placed (imprint, or in the footer of every page that shows some tags)?

Comment: Yes.  And in the footer should be fine. This (kind of) question has been asked before but don't ask me to dig up the references. ;)

Comment: I swear I searched for "tags, attribution, legal" but found nothing useful. Anyway thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Related/probably dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248434/stack-exchange-api-licensing-compliance

Comment: Recent and closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279967/gathering-and-reporting-se-site-stats